# Jump to Top Link in Plugin

Tags: php, html, css, plugins

I am using this plugin to make a list of all the Categories on my Wordpress blog :

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=T6rvtwkS

The script can be seen in action here :

www.animefushigi.com/full-anime-list

Now, I want to add a link to Top of page under each set of alphebetical listings, so right after each

I want to add this :

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">
Top
</a>
```

Where and How can I implement that in the plugin script???

Example of what I mean is :
www.voober.com/anime-series-list/

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it looks like you could do this near the end of the `ddmcc_generate` function:

```
$t_out .= "</ul>\n</div>";  //<-- existing line

// your new code
$t_out .= '<div><a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">Top</a></div>';
```

Not sure that you need the `<div>`.  I put it in there to wrap the link in a block.